# log of a complex valued function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on a homework in complex analysis, and I just don't know how to go about this problem.

Suppose f is holomorphic on a domain Gamma and has no zero in Gamma. Prove that log|f| is harmonic in Gamma by computing its Laplacian.

I'm not sure how to get started. I figured that it had something to do with the definition of log(f)=log|f|+i*arg(f), and I know the laplacian, but I'm not sure how to take it from there. Any ideas?

Comment: $|f|=(u^2+v^2)^{1/2}$ is a real-valued fuction.  Use the fact that both $u$ and $v$ are harmonic and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.